# Nested Attributes when Viewing Multiple Models (not a form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view, models, nested-attributes

I am having trouble rendering a model's attributes in foreign model's view. I think it is a nested attributes problem because `f.bike` works but `f.bike.biketype` gives an undefined method error. Below is my error and code. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Error from Browser:

```
NoMethodError in Carts#show

Showing /Users/willdennis/rails_projects/spinlister/app/views/carts/show.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `biketype' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <h2>Your Cart</h2>
2:  <ul>
3:      <% @cart.line_items.each do |f| %>
4:      <li><%= f.bike.biketype %></li>
5:      <% end %>
6:  </ul>
```

views/carts/show.html.erb

```
<h2>Your Cart</h2>
<ul>
    <% @cart.line_items.each do |f| %>
    <li><%= f.bike.biketype %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

cart.rb

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items

  attr_accessible :bike_id, :name, :description, :size, :biketype, :price, :photo, :id, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :latitude, :longitude, :neighborhood 
end
```

line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bike
  belongs_to :cart

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bike, :cart

  attr_accessible :name, :description, :size, :biketype, :price, :photo, :id, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :latitude, :longitude, :neighborhood 

end
```

bike.rb

```
class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :line_items

attr_accessible :name, :description, :size, :biketype, :price, :photo, :id, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :latitude, :longitude, :neighborhood 

end
```

carts_controller.rb

```
  def show
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: Are you sure each line_item in your database actually has an associated bike? The error suggests that one of the bike objects is nil, which is what you expect if there is a line_item with bike_id nil or referring to a non-existent bike.

Comment: I think you may be right. When I checked my database the line_items did not have bike_id's. Here is my line_items_controller: `def create @cart = current_cart
    bike = Bike.find(params[:bike_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:bike_id => bike)` Any idea how to correctly add the bike_id to the line_item? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is telling you that the object f.bike is of class nil. You would have been expecting it to be an instance of class Bike. Obviously you have a line item in your view that doesn't have a bike record attached to it.
To take care of the error so your view will display just add a check for blank?

```
li><%= f.bike.biketype unless f.bike.blank? || f.bike.biketype.blank? %></li>
```

As to why you have a line item with no bike? Well that's an entirely different question and there is not enough info here to answer that.

**UPDATE Based on comments below**
Your button_to looks a little wrong. Try

```
<%= button_to "Rent this Bicycle!", {line_items_path(:bike_id => @bike)}, {:id => "rentthisbike"} %>
```

Using the curly braces ensures that Rails knows the second param is a css style not a param to be passed into the controllers action
To check if your bike id is getting into the controller then check the params that are actually getting into the controller action that add the bike to the line item. You will be able to find this in your development.log file, find the post request for the action and one of the first lines in that action will list all the params. If you see the bike_id in that list then either one of 2 possible situations is occurring.
1) You are not accessing the params hash properly to get the bike id from it
or
2) You are not setting the bike ID on the line item before saving the record.

You should be able to access the id using `params[:bike_id]`
If you don't see the bike id then you need to look again at the button_to code to see why it's not passing the bike ID

**End of update**

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes that helps. Thanks. I think the problem is passing the bike_id to the line_item. I have `<%= button_to "Rent this Bicycle!", line_items_path(:bike_id => @bike.id), :id => "rentthisbike" %>` in my bike/view/show and `def create
    @cart = current_cart
    @bike = Bike.find(params[:bike_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:bike_id => @bike) end` in my line_items_controller.rb. Any thoughts? I believe the line_item is being built incorrectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Will Dennis, I have updated my answer accordingly, although it;s really difficult answer without the full picture. Maybe this should be another question if what I gave you doesn't work so detail around the issue of setting the bike on the line item can be focused on. Include the params hash and controller code that save the bike to the line item in any further posts to enable the issue to be diagnosed more clearly

Comment: thanks for your help. I've tried to specify the issue and have included the development log POST here. Seems the params are correct put not posting the correct bike_id value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905417/button-to-not-passing-correct-id-from-params-hash

Comment: I'll have a look at that question, but don't forget you will have legacy data that is still wrong. Is this still not working for new line items?